# Failed to convert from a string to a int32

Tags: c#, database, winforms

i got a problem where i only be able to retrieve the data from the database on a single textbox. What i want is, i want to retrieve the data of every textboxes from the database, but when i tried, getting error:

Here is the code:

```
string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxCodeContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxQuantityContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxDescContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxSubTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();
private List<List<TextBox>> textBoxTotalContainer = new List<List<TextBox>>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    UpdateTextPosition();

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Code] FROM [Data]", conn);

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
         string numString = dReader[0].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
         codesCollection.Add(numString);
    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void UpdateDatas()
{    
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Description], [Price] FROM [Data] WHERE [Code]=@Code", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text;

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        this.textBoxDescContainer[0][0].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
        this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][0].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I already tried add:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text;
```

and

```
while (dReader.Read())
{
    this.textBoxDescContainer[0][1].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
    this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][1].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
}
```

but i got an error which says: "Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a int32"

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: From the suggestions that have failed, it looks like you have a data issue.  Show us the sample data?  It could be Code or Price contain non-integers.

Comment: always use cultreinfo while converting from string to numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

you have to parse the **string** to **Int32** DataType

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value =int.Parse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text);
```

This should work if user enters a valid integer

For e.g.

```
int Val=int.Parse("45");//Works for me
```

**Note:** This does not work for decimal values

Alternatively If your `Price` value contains Decimal what you can do is

```
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text));
```

This should work

Comment: i already tried, but the error says: input string was not in correct format. what happen? --"

Comment: @Fuhans Take a look at my updated answer does your input contains Decimal values ?? like 45.21 or 79.45?? something like that??

Comment: for the code, the number is not in decimal value, but for the price, it contains decimal values in the database, which are "10.000,00"

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text);
```

Comment: i already tried, but the error says: input string was not in correct format. what happen? --"

Comment: I would suggest http://stackoverflow.com/a/18267369/503110 answer. May all the text in `textBoxCodeContainer` text box won't convert to int and in such case your code will blow. Use `int.TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text;
```

needs to be changed to

```
int codeValue;
if(int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text,out codeValue))
  cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = codeValue;
else
  { 
    //do some error handling of invalid input
  }
```

as you are trying to pass a string to parameter of type ineteger.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][0].Text=Convert.ToInt32(dReader["Price"].ToString());
```

The above statement should help you...

Regards

Anurag

Comment: i already tried, but the error says: cannot implicity convert type int to string

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, which you don't really mention where the error is raised, this seem to be the source of your problem.

```
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
            cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text;
```

You have declared "`Code`" as an `Integer` but you are assigning a `Text` value. Convert this to `Int32`.

```
Int32 codeValue = 0; 
Int32.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text, out codeValue); 
cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer); 
cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = codeValue;
```

Comment: i already tried that way, but the error says: input string was not in correct format. what happen? --"